# Haskell processing of Javascript "click" to get the link

Tags: javascript, html, haskell, html-parsing

folks. Maybe you could help with the following problem (some workaround is pretty fine).

I need automatic loading BibTex record (or some other record with full authors list and journal/book/etc. name) from Google Scholar. As for now I could form a request URL and download search results page (e.g. like this one: http://bit.ly/1ddg1re). On this page to get a BibTex record the one should click on *Cite* link (which is JavaScript, as I understand) and then click on the link *Import to BibTex* (which is just a usual GET link to a text, containing BibText record).

So I could load pages from usual GET URLs, but my problem is to do this "click on JavaScript link and get the resulting page" in Haskell. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: This isn't completely clear to me.  Do you want to build a GUI in Haskell, say, using gtk2hs or something similar, or do you want to serve HTML/javascript up to a browser using Yesod?  Or is it something else completely?  What will we do with do with the data once is has been fetched?  Will we need to set up a database, or will the data come from the web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On the first page search for the the "Cite" link of the publication you're interested. In the example you provided it would look like this:

   `<a onclick="return gs_ocit(event,'gwx5nEs8alwJ','0')" ...>Cite</a>`

   The second argument of `gs_ocit` is the `ID`, the third argument is the `SCIRP`.
2. Make a GET HTTP request to `http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=info:<ID>:scholar.google.com/&output=cite&scirp=<SCIRP>&hl=en` substituting `<ID>` and `<SCIRP>` with the values obtained in the previous step.
3. Search for the "Import BibTex" link. It will look something like the following:

   `<a ... href="/scholar.bib?q=info:gwx5nEs8alwJ:scholar.google.com/&amp;output=citation&amp;scisig=AAGBfm0AAAAAUqhCtMOkKUkPe4VNc7E6kPW-SRLxTbBL&amp;scisf=4&amp;hl=en">Import into BibTeX</a>`

   Get the the URL in `href` attribute, make a GET request to it, and you're done.